# Converting MovieClips in an fla to bmp

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a game that I made in flash, and now I want to take all the movieclips I have and export the images into something that I can use outside of flash.  What would be the easiest way to do this?  I would rather not use screenshots, plus, I need to keep the transparency.

Comment: If you want to keep the transparency then you'll want to stay away from the bmp format mentioned in your title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/), in particular [swfextract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html) to extract your MovieClips as PNG images. PNG images can contain and will preserve the transparencies. If you would like to convert the result to some other image format, you can use the [convert](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/convert.html) command provided by the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JPEGEncoder](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/)?